# Gatling Pebble Templating

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, pebble

I am having issues resolving the dot (.) notation of pebble templating in Gatling to retrieve attributes of variables, such as Map key values.

Here's an example of a session attribute that I've defined:

```
session => session.set("location", Map("text" -> "Alabama"))
```

I'm trying to replace {{ location.text }} in the following json template file with the value "Alabama":

```
...
   "text": "{{ location.text }}",
...
```

However, it looks like Gatling is unable to resolve the attribute, and therefore, the result is an empty string.

I am using version 3.2.1 of Gatling.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/23CuH88x1Vo

Since Pebble is a Java library...
after converting the map to a java.util.Map datatype using scala.collection.JavaConverters, I was able to successfully use Pebble dot (.) notation for traversing the map.